# How to call Parse locally in web page when hosting Parse server?

Tags: express, parse-platform, parse-server

I built a reactjs app using express that's hosted on heroku. I'm also using Parse and hosting it on the same app on heroku.

I was wondering if there's a way to locally call Parse, instead of specifying the Parse SERVER URL (which is basically at the same place as my app).

Can I set the SERVER URL to an absolute path instead?

Comment: What about `http://localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

To run parse-server locally make sure you have node added to your environment variables and go to your apps main directory in cmd. Call "node index.js" and if you've setup your parse-server correctly it should specify a http://localhost:port
address at which it's being hosted. Open that address in your browser and viola. You're hosting parse-server locally.